# Change value in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I try to change the values from matrix `A` below.

```
A=[1; 1; 2; 2]

A =

     1
     1
     2
     2
```

which want to change into target  matrix `B`

```
B = [1 0;1 0;0 1;0 1]

B =

     1     0
     1     0
     0     1
     0     1
```

I can not change, please guide me some example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `bsxfun` You can write:

```
B = bsxfun(@eq,A,1:2)
```

or in Octave or Matlab R2016b:

```
B = A==1:2
```